# quality vector incorrectly updated while interpolating matlab timeseries object

Tags: matlab, time-series, interpolation, floating-point-precision

Running the following matlab code:

```
% define new timeseries object, set Quality vector to zero
a=timeseries( ...
  [1:6]', ...
  [datenum('2010-1-1 0:00'):1/24:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59')]', ...
  zeros(6,1) ...
);
% set meta data for new timeseries object
a.QualityInfo.Code = 0:1;
a.TimeInfo.Units = 'days';
a.TimeInfo.Increment = 1/24; 
a.TimeInfo.Format = 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS';
a.TimeInfo.StartDate = datestr(0);

% extrapolate timevector and interpolate for half hours. 
b=resample(a, ...
  datenum('2009-12-31 21:00'):1/48:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59'), ...
  'linear', ...
  1 ...
)
```

Gives output:

```
    Time vector characteristics

          Length                18
          Start date            31-Dec-2009 21:00:00
          End date              01-Jan-2010 05:30:00

    Data characteristics

          Interpolation method  linear
          Size                  [18   1]
          Data type             double

    Time                              Data                              Quality
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    31-Dec-2009 21:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 21:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:30:00              NaN                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 00:00:00              1                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 00:30:00              1.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 01:00:00              2                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 01:30:00              2.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 02:00:00              3                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 02:30:00              3.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 03:00:00              4                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 03:30:00              4.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 04:00:00              5                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 04:30:00              5.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 05:00:00              6                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 05:30:00              NaN                                 1
```

While I would expect output:

```
    Time vector characteristics

          Length                18
          Start date            31-Dec-2009 21:00:00
          End date              01-Jan-2010 05:30:00

    Data characteristics

          Interpolation method  linear
          Size                  [18   1]
          Data type             double

    Time                              Data                              Quality
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    31-Dec-2009 21:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 21:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:30:00              NaN                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 00:00:00              1                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 00:30:00              1.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 01:00:00              2                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 01:30:00              2.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 02:00:00              3                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 02:30:00              3.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 03:00:00              4                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 03:30:00              4.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 04:00:00              5                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 04:30:00              5.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 05:00:00              6                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 05:30:00              NaN                                 1
```

The difference between the given output and the expected output is that the Quality vector should only be set to 1 for the interpolated and extrapolated values and not to the unchanged values.

In the Matlab documentation is written that only the quality code of the observations that have changed should be changed by the interpolate function. As is shown in this example this is not the case.

Is there a workaround?

My matlab version is: MATLAB Version 7.9.1.705 (R2009b) Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround myself:

When you look into the built-in Matlab function \toobox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries\resample.m on line 192 is written:

```
I = isnan(yin) | abs(yout-yin)>eps;
```

On this line it is determined which indici (stored in I) will get Qualtity code 1.

Usually the difference between yout and yin is much larger, in this case the difference is:

```
yout-yin
```

returns:

```
    ans =

      1.0e-008 *

             0
       -0.1118
       -0.1118
       -0.1118
```

while eps is: 2.2204e-016

By lowering the a.Data we are able to work around the bug in the Matlab built-in function::

```
% extrapolate timevector and interpolate for half hours. 
CorrectionFactor = 1/max(max(a.Data))/1e7;
a.Data = a.Data * CorrectionFactor ;
b=resample(a, ...
  datenum('2009-12-31 21:00'):1/48:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59'), ...
  'linear', ...
  1 ...
);
b.Data = b.Data / CorrectionFactor;
b
```

The will give as output:

```
          Length                18
          Start date            31-Dec-2009 21:00:00
          End date              01-Jan-2010 05:30:00

    Data characteristics

          Interpolation method  linear
          Size                  [18   1]
          Data type             double

    Time                              Data                              Quality
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    31-Dec-2009 21:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 21:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:30:00              NaN                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 00:00:00              1                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 00:30:00              1.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 01:00:00              2                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 01:30:00              2.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 02:00:00              3                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 02:30:00              3.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 03:00:00              4                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 03:30:00              4.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 04:00:00              5                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 04:30:00              5.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 05:00:00              6                                   1
    01-Jan-2010 05:30:00              NaN                                 1
```

As you can see there is still a problem for **01-Jan-2010 02:00:00** and  **01-Jan-2010 05:00:00**, this can be solved by adjusting the way the time vector is defined. We need to replace:

```
datenum('2010-1-1 0:00'):1/24:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59')
```

with

```
(datenum('2010-1-1 0:00')*24:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59')*24)/24
```

The complete solution will be:

```
% define new timeseries object, set Quality vector to zero
a=timeseries( ...
  [1:6]', ...
  [(datenum('2010-1-1 0:00')*24:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59')*24)/24]', ...
  zeros(6,1) ...
);
% set meta data for new timeseries object
a.QualityInfo.Code = 0:1;
a.TimeInfo.Units = 'days';
a.TimeInfo.Increment = 1/24; 
a.TimeInfo.Format = 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS';
a.TimeInfo.StartDate = datestr(0);

% extrapolate timevector and interpolate for half hours. 
CorrectionFactor = 1/max(max(a.Data))/1e7;
a.Data = a.Data * CorrectionFactor ;
b=resample(a, ...
  (datenum('2009-12-31 21:00')*48:datenum('2010-1-1 05:59')*48)/48, ...
  'linear', ...
  1 ...
);
b.Data = b.Data / CorrectionFactor;
b
```

and this gives the output which we would exepect:

```
    Time vector characteristics

          Length                18
          Start date            31-Dec-2009 21:00:00
          End date              01-Jan-2010 05:30:00

    Data characteristics

          Interpolation method  linear
          Size                  [18   1]
          Data type             double

    Time                              Data                              Quality
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    31-Dec-2009 21:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 21:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 22:30:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:00:00              NaN                                 1
    31-Dec-2009 23:30:00              NaN                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 00:00:00              1                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 00:30:00              1.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 01:00:00              2                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 01:30:00              2.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 02:00:00              3                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 02:30:00              3.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 03:00:00              4                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 03:30:00              4.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 04:00:00              5                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 04:30:00              5.5                                 1
    01-Jan-2010 05:00:00              6                                   0
    01-Jan-2010 05:30:00              NaN                                 1
```